# WebIoPi buttons don't show up over Internet even with port-forwarding

Tags: networking, web-interface, webiopi

I am trying to setup my RPi to access over the Internet and tried to setup a simple rule to port forward to RPi.

I see the buttons and a camera feed if I access the WebIoPi over the local Intranet. However, if I try to access via the Internet using my public IP address and same port number then I only see the camera feed but not the buttons.

Any tips or ideas what I could have done wrong? I have attached two pictures to give an idea of what is going wrong. The first image shows the working case where the browser points to 192.x.y.z:8008. Buttons show up. The second points to 99.x.y.z:8008 and only the title of the page and camera feed shows. This suggests that at least the external machine can get to the Raspberry Pi and get the index.html but not the javascript buttons for some reason.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you are port forwarding correctly - are you sure the ISP isn't stopping it - answer these before asking for help.

Comment: Well, actually no. I am not sure if I did the port forwarding correctly. It appears that I did setup something - because without the forwarding of the port 8008 to my RPi, the webpage couldn't be reached. Now I can reach with my external IP address but the buttons don't show up. Other text on the page shows up.